# Undeclared identifier in Code Insight?

Tags: delphi

```
unit lc

type

TSite = class(TObject)
...
public
  function BlockRef_Delete( AlcBlockRef: THandle ): integer;
...
```

---

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  ... lc ...;

var
  Site: TSite;
```

At any place in unit 'main', where im using any of the 'Site's method, i get Undeclared identifier {Site's method name here}.

I checked the unit files path's also there is no other dcu or pas in the project.

Interesting, that even the 'Free' method of 'Site' cannot be seen by code insight.

Otherwise, the project compiles. IDE: Delphi 2010.

Comment: Please show an MCVE. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Code Insight is defunctional. Do not trust that information.

Comment: Sometimes a clean and compile will correct this...depends on which version of Delphi.  Newer versions seem less prone to code and error insight problems, but none are what I would consider fully functional.  Lots of circular references seem to exacerbate the issue.  Wonky line endings can also be to blame.  I don't use it, but Andy's IDE Fix Pack addresses some of the problems some of the time... http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

Comment: Many times this gets resolved by simply opening up one of the units being used in the IDE. This insight has always been broken and unreliable.

Comment: Could it be that the compiler is finding a different version of lc.pas which doesn't include the declaration of TSite?  Btw, it would help if you added the real code of lc.pas, not the fake code you've quoted.

Comment: You should edit your question and put real code - a more complete example. As of now, your title and question don't match. I suggest don't even mention free if free is just one of the many problematic things (as I understand).

Comment: @MartynA seems the problem is something like that. But i dont find any other definition/declaration of TSite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some another unit declares `TSite` type that is used instead;

Try declare the var awith the fully qualified name

```
unit main; uses .. lc, ...;
var
  Site: lc.TSite;
```

Also it would make sense to reference the var via FQ-name too, just I ncase some other unit or procedure declare some function or variable with the name "Site"

```
unit main; uses .. lc, ...;
var
  Site: lc.TSite;

....
  main.Site := lc.TSite.Create;
....
  main.Site.Free;
```

PS: if your `lc` unit uses some other units you may specialize the tye declaration as well: `type TSite = class(System.TObject);`

Comment: OP says everything compiles and runs just fine, which means this is not the issue. The issue is how broken the Delphi IDE Code Insight is. I have this precise problem all the time.

Comment: @JerryDodge that is a possible interpretation . Another is that the project compiles if to remove calls to Site's methods, and CodeInsight there only mentioned with regard to ".free" method.

Comment: A quick test to verify this, in the same unit where `TSite` is defined, create another class with a non-standard name (such as `TSomeTest`). I'll bet the same thing happens. Whenever I see this, it applies to everything in a unit, not just one class. Also, OP's use of "`{Site's method name here}`" tells me it's more than just `Free`. Besides, `Free` is a standard part of all objects - it should exist even if it's the wrong class.

Comment: Free might be missing if (1) it is not the class at all, or (2) mentioned TObject is not

Comment: But then nothing would be able to compile either.

Comment: true. but this whole answer is based on the interpretation that "Otherwise *when commenting out everything related to problematic TSite*, the project compiles."

Comment: I don't see anything even remotely related to commenting anything out.

Comment: This what happens if we all try to guess. We should have closed the question right off the bat and made the asker fix it to include an MCVE. By lacking discipline we end up with all the pointless speculation. 5 close votes forcing the asker to learn how as a real question is actually what the asker needs.

Comment: @Arioch'The Thank You that did the trick (main.Site.Free), but then, how can i find the another definition of TSite? I checked all the units in the project, the project source, all the units and paths at project manager etc...

Comment: if the trick was in `main.Site.Free` then the duplicated term is not `tsite` but the `site` - a local variable or function argument, or maybe some property of the form or some other record/object, or anything like that. Try Ctrl+Click on non-qualified Site, or right-click and "find declaration"

Comment: @Arioch'The I checked all the 'site' presence (Search/Find In Files) and there is no other declaration, strange. Also i reference the main's global 'site' declaration in other units without problems. Now im 99% sure its some circular unit reference.

Comment: in the Delphi RTL/VCL sources there might be too // either it is declared in some procedure or class, or in some unit you "uses" in "implementation" of main. Other units do not see those local to main things, so they only see the var declared in "interface" of main and nothing else

Comment: "circular reference" is an absolutely different thing, nothing in common

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes thats make sense. Renamed reference 'site' with refractor, all fine. Thank you.

Comment: Ide FixPack add-on has an extended "file in files" service AFAIR // or there is Grep in GExperts. Also you might try "rename in unit"  ()much simpler and limited but much faster than J#-based Refactor) from CnWizards (less polished of those, but their syntax highlighting rocks when not too slow). - would you have time - give those add-ons a run